# Lenovo Laptop: 2 short beeps, pause, 3 short beeps

Tags: boot, bios, lenovo-laptop

My **Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon** laptop has problems with its BIOS and motherboard information. It boots unreliably, getting stuck on a black screen when it fails. The times it boots successfully, it throws random errors from a pool, such as:

- `0187: EAIA data access error.`
- `0251: System CMOS Checksum bad - Default configuration used.`
- `2200: Machine Type and Serial Number are invalid.`
- `2201: Machine UUID is invalid.`

I'm updating my BIOS [as per this tutorial](http://positon.org/lenovo-thinkpad-bios-update-with-linux-and-usb), booting through a USB Stick. The laptop is connected to the AC.

The utility asked me the administrator password, and after some instructions and waiting, it rebooted, and has spent *over an hour* on a black screen, with the power light slowly phasing in and out.

Even though a BIOS update is a very delicate matter, I figure it can't take that long, but *when I touch the power off button, **it sounds two short beeps, followed by three more short beeps**, and the power remains on*. This sequence is not covered in the [documentation](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht035729).

What does it mean? Is it reasonably safe to hold the button and turn off the laptop?

Comment: At this point in time you are not going to do anymore damage than is already done.  Go head and power it off and report the results to us.

Comment: I had to wait until the battery died off because it didn't shut off no matter how long I held the button. As soon as I plugged the laptop to AC, I confirmed there was no damage, and the BIOS updated. I'll leave the question open in case somebody knows what the beeps meant, for the sake of closure.

Comment: I had the same case (2 beeps + 3 beeps after a BIOS upgrade on a P50). It could not be powered off, I took away the battery. It restarted with an alarming `Secure flash authentication failed!` and powered off. After powering it on again it started normally.

Comment: For me worked waiting until the battery went off. Then I just booted laptop fine (Ubuntu 20, lenovo thinkpad x1 carbon)

Answer (score 1):

On a Carbon X1 4th Gen, the following worked for me for the 2 beep, pause, 3 beep (unable to power off) situation.

Use a paperclip and push gently into the small reset hole.

Link: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/X1-Carbon-4th-gen-not-starting-up-nor-charging/m-p/4193294?page=1#4193401

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1136194)

Comment: OMG thanks so much, I thought I had bricked it!